# Eclipse sync with svn repo is not available for Maven import project

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven-scm

I have checked in a maven multi module project.If I check in in normal way, as "import - svn Checkout projects from svn" , then the main project is checked in as one folder and it is possible to team -> sync with repositary.

But as the main project is a maven project with multiple modules in it, I tried "import - maven - checkout maven project from scm", selected svn from the drop down list and checked in.Project check in fine.Not only the parent folder, but it lays out all the modules seperately too so that we can work in them individually.The question is, I cant, team ->sync with repositary. That option is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. You have to right click on the project and give share project...